# Testing client server application using emulator

Tags: android, glassfish, vaadin

My server application is created using **vaadin** and deployed in **glassfish** but it is on **localhost**.

I have created a android project which communicates with this server.

How should i test my android application ?

Comment: Use 10.0.2.2, explained [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking).

Comment: use you own pc's ip address. like http://"your ip"/

Comment: Give your localhost address as http://192.168.x.x:xxxx

Comment: Do i have to give port number also like http://xxx.xxx.x.x:8082/ApplicationName/